# Camera will not work in Skype in 10.8.5

Tags: camera, facetime, skype

I have a MacBook Air 13", bought about a month ago, running OS X 10.8.5. The camera is recorded in System Information as:

```
FaceTime HD Camera:

  Model ID:     Apple Camera VendorID_0x106B ProductID_0x1570
  Unique ID:    CC2332357XYF9T9CA
```

The camera worked in Skype very well until last night when I installed the latest upgrade from Apple. After that, the camera will not work in Skype although it works on PhotoBooth and iChat. In the preferences Skype declares that there is no camera. I reboot the system a few times. I unistalled and reinstalled Skype (the latest and some of the earlier versions). I performed SMC and PRAM and I fixed the permissions. I open Photo Booth while Skype was running. Nothing worked.

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Apple issued a patch to go on top of the 10.8.5 update that didn't ship both a 32bit and 64 bit file that Skype, Apple's iMovie and other apps need to run the internal camera.

> After some investigation, we have found that the OSX 10.8.5 update is missing a specific file that would allow some apps such as Skype or iMovie to access the built-in facetime camera on Mid-2013 MacBook Airs.
>
> The 10.8.5 update updated a CoreMediaIO plugin that accesses the MBA camera, but didn't bundle the 32-bits version of it.

[Source: Skype Community Post](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/OS-X-10-8-5-Broke-Skype-Video/td-p/1891729/page/2)

Also, you can use an external camera in the mean time if you need to run on 10.8.5 and the affected Air.

Comment: The video on Skype is working fine on MacBook Pro with 10.8.5. It seems an issue for MacBook Air only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Alert!, I will hold off with 10.8.5 till issue resolved.

Someone suggested to use the driver from 10.8.4, but I can not verify that solution.

Go to folder /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/
Replace the AppleCamera.plugin with 10.8.4 version

Comment: Thanks! The answer begs the question though: where would I find 10.8.4 version of AppleCamera.plugin? I didn't configure Time Machine before updating so cannot roll back. Are bits and pieces of 10.8.4, such as AppleCamera.plugin, available for download somewhere?

Comment: @Michael First a word of serious WARNING. System files from Internet that are not from Apple could be dangerous. With that said here is the link for the file. Scroll down and you will find it in a post from Mr. Zarniwoop  http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1636837

Comment: Also, modifying files like this should be done if you have a good full backup or are comfortable reinstalling your entire OS if later patches break further on your modified system. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104534/camera-not-working-again-on-mid-2013-macbook-air-after-the-second-10-8-5-upgrade for details.